# Fan speed, temperature and direction cannot be changed

Tags: bmw, heater-blower

I own a BMW E81 (2009).

I attempted to replace the standard stereo with a double DIN touch screen. I followed the steps as located [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mfF8GFz1t5s), with the same fascia.

My radio required power to the fuse box, and I tested the fuses and found an empty fuse at 12V which I connected to when ignition was on and the headunit behaves as it should, but as I tried putting it all back together I have a problem with the manual aircon unit ([as pictured here](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/F58AAOSwaEhZFaEV/s-l1600.jpg)).

Basically, with the ignition on and cables connected the fans are on full speed and aimed towards demisting the window. None of the spinner controls do anything, I can't control the fan direction, the fan speed or temperature. The buttons (demist rear, aircon and circulate air) all work and function correctly.

Any ideas what I have done? I may have broken the unit disconnecting it, but I'd expect may one or two controls to work, not all spinners.

It's work noting that in the YouTube video there is a ribbon connection which connects the aircon unit to the traction control panel. I had that connected but the traction button didn't light up when pressed but I think that may be a seperate issue, so for now I have been testing with both the BMW harnesses connected to the aircon unit, but the ribbon connecting the aircon unit to the traction control panel is disconnected.

Comment: The fact that the system goes to high blower speed and Defrost mode tells me there is a disconnect between the controls on the instrument panel and the logic unit for the door actuators / fan. That setting is safety default mode (by federal specs). You’ve pulled or broken a wire somewhere.